# Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying out the new version 2.0 of AFNetworking and I'm getting the error above. Any idea why this is happening? Here's my code:

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:kJSONlink];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

I'm using Xcode 5.0.

Also, here's the error message:

```
Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0xda2e670 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=kJSONlink, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xda35180> { URL: kJSONlink } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 2898;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 01 Oct 2013 10:59:45 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}
```

I just hid the JSON using kJSONlink. This should return a JSON.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

This means that your server is sending `"text/html"` instead of the already supported types.
My solution was to add `"text/html"` to `acceptableContentTypes` set in `AFURLResponseSerialization` class. Just search for "acceptableContentTypes" and add `@"text/html"` to the set manually.

Of course, the ideal solution is to change the type sent from the server, but for that you will have to talk with the server team.

Comment: Thanks! I just added this code to make it work: `op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];`

Comment: For PHP it's as easy as adding this to the page: header("Content-Type: application/json"); (unless it's not a JSON response, then XML or something)

Comment: @rckehoe  Thanks for this - much preferred to change the page header than `acceptableContentTypes` :)

Comment: An alternative to @jaytrixz comment is to just _add_ a new content type to the already existing ones: `op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];`

Comment: If you are dealing with standard API you will never have to do that, adding text/html as a type and sending JSON is bad practice. Changing server code is proper solution.

Comment: Swift code: `op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(object: "text/html")`

Comment: Thanks dude! self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

Comment: Adding one more content type to the existing set is the possible way                  AFHTTPSessionManager_insatnce.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [AFHTTPSessionManager_insatnce.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

Comment: If that happens in Parse.com platform that because you used the wrong keys such as restAPI key and not client key, etc

Comment: Swift 2.2 is like the following ```NSSet(object: "text/html") as? Set<String>```

Answer (score 179):

Setting my `RequestOperationManager` Response Serializer to `HTTPResponseSerializer` fixed the issue.

**Objective-C**

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

**Swift**

```
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
```

Making this change means I don't need to add `acceptableContentTypes` to every request I make.

Comment: I made this and it crashes my app. Reverting back to using `AFJSONResponseSerializer`

Comment: @jaytrixz It depends, If your server always responds with JSON you should set the `responseSerializer` to `AFJSONResponseSerializer`.

Comment: You will now receive the responseObject as NSData and need to parse the JSON in the success block.

Comment: Because I am using pods, so this way is better.

Comment: @Danpe,  How to convert above line of code into Swift. I tried with  manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer.serializer() but no use.

Comment: Hey @G.Ganesh I updated my answer, try `manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer.serializer()`

Comment: The Swift version should be `manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()`

Comment: @ Danpe, You are my Hero for the Day........ Thanks Buddy, works like a charm.....

Answer (score 73):

I took @jaytrixz's answer/comment one step further and added "text/html" to the existing set of types.  That way when they fix it on the server side to "application/json" or "text/json" I claim it'll work seamlessly.

```
  manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

Comment: Agreed. The accepted answer to this question has a huge flaw in that it creates a time bomb that will explode when the server side is fixed to return the correct content type.

Comment: This seems right in theory but has anyone actually tested this?

Answer (score 33):

On the server side, I added:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

into my .php code and this also fixed the problem.

Comment: `if(!headers_sent() ) {
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
  }`

Is a nice fix

Answer (score 18):

I solve this problem from a different perspective.

I think if the server sends JSON data with `Content-Type: text/html` header. It doesn't mean the server guy intended to send you some html but accidentally changed to JSON. It does mean the server guy just doesn't care about what the `Content-Type` header is. So if the server guy doesn't care as the client side you better ignore the `Content-Type` header as well. To ignore the `Content-Type` header check in `AFNetworking`

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;
```

In this way the `AFJSONResponseSerializer` (the default one) will serialize the JSON data without checking `Content-Type` in response header.

Comment: Exactly correct.  By ignoring the content type I do not receive my content as a hex code, nor as a failed nil response.  This works great!  Thank you

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to enable to receive "text/plain" content type:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```

Similarly if you wish to enable "text/html" content type:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried below line as per @Andrie answer but didn't work,

```
op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

so after hunting more, I did work around to get it work successfully.

Here is my code snip.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonResponseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSMutableSet *jsonAcceptableContentTypes = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
    [jsonAcceptableContentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
    jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = jsonAcceptableContentTypes;
    operation.responseSerializer = jsonResponseSerializer;
```

Hope this will help someone out there.

Comment: +1. This is definitively the solution. Since you have to set the acceptable Content Type both on the Serializer if this is a JSON serializer (that is normally using "application/json") and the operation. Otherwise you will get an error settings on operation only.

Answer (score 3):

This is the only thing that I found to work

```
-(void) testHTTPS {
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", HOST] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone is using `AFHTTPSessionManager` then one can do like this to solve the issue,

I subclassed `AFHTTPSessionManager` where I'm doing like this,

```
NSMutableSet *contentTypes = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
[contentTypes addObject:@"text/html"];
self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = contentTypes;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I don't have control over server setting, but I know it's expecting "application/json" for "Content-Type". I did this on the iOS client side:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

refer to
[AFNetworking version 2 content-type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321000/afnetworking-version-2-content-type-error)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line :

```
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

Answer (score 1):

A good question always have multiple answers, to reduce and help you choose the right answer, here I am adding my own too. I have tested it and it works fine.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourdomain.com/appname/data/ws/index.php/user/login/"]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"POST" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
    //Now convert json string to dictionary.
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a somehow similar problem working with AFNetworking from a Swift codebase so I'm just leaving this here in the remote case someone is as unlucky as me having to work in such a setup. *If you are, I feel you buddy, stay strong!*

The operation was failing due to "unacceptable content-type", despite me actually setting the `acceptableContentTypes` with a `Set` containing the content type value in question.

The solution for me was to tweak the Swift code to be more Objective-C friendly, *I guess*:

```
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["application/xml", "text/xml", "text/plain"]) as Set<NSObject>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"decline_clicked.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);


NSString *queryStringss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://119.9.77.121/lets_chat/index.php/webservices/uploadfile/"];
queryStringss = [queryStringss stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];


[manager POST:queryStringss parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {


     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"fileName" fileName:@"decline_clicked.png" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];



 }
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {



    NSDictionary *dict = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Result"];

    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];


 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
     NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
 }];
```