# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking library to post data on server using POST method.

Following is my code

```
- (void) callLoginAPI:(NSDictionary *)dictProfile{
    // 1
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dictProfile valueForKey:@"name"], @"username",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"first_name"],@"first_name",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"last_name"],@"last_name",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"email"],@"email",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"birthday"],@"dob",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"gender"],@"gender",
                                                                    [[dictProfile valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"name"],@"location",
                                                                    [dictProfile valueForKey:@"timezone"],@"timezone",
                                                                    @"",@"language",
                                                                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",[dictProfile valueForKey:@"id"]],@"profile_pic_url",
                                                                    @"",@"cover_pic_url",nil];



    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];



    [manager POST:@"http://10.1.81.35:8000/api/login/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

but I got following error in response

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x797f2620 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I can't understand what is the problem with the code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem comes from response parsing. 
You are trying to de-serialize a `JSON` reponse (which MUST be contained in either a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`) however your response is none of the above (Most likely a simple string).

Also, try to set the "allow fragments" to the response serializer.

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
```

Answer (score 14):

May be you need authentication to access `JSON` response. Set authentication like that:

```
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"XYZ" password:@"xyzzzz"];
```

Try this:

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[self setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
```

instead of:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: Great answer showing where this code needs to be input. A small detail but very important

Comment: I was stuck on this issue for a while, tried everything in this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0 but your answer was the one that worked.

Comment: @iDeveloper Thanks it worked for me... struggling with it for a while... 1 upvote

Comment: @iDeveloper Please tell me what is [self setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer]; as i get error here

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

//Request Serializer
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

//Response Serializer
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
```