# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed in iOS using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I  am using AFNetworking to get the data from server using post methods in iOS but i am getting status code **200 OK** but in **AFNetworking**  its comes in Failure methods and its display below error  I have also search on google and i have tried based on result also but its display same error.

Waiting for your reply.

**Status code :-**

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Type" = "text/html"
```

> **Error :-** Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7f838a5df950 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

**Here is my code :-**

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *result;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictPost
                options:kNilOptions    error:&error];
if (! jsonData) {
} else {

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];

}

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[manager setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];*


[manager POST:@“http:www.server.url.com” parameters:result success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@“Error: %@", error.description);

}];
```

Comment: Could you please reformat the code?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I have the same problem and all the solutions I have tried on this linke and a few others haven't worked --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0

Comment: @Allen I have resolved above issue .

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26233841/269108).

There is probably an error in the response itself, which cannot be parsed as a valid JSON.

I'd try to debug the server response using a 3rd party tool, such as Postman for Chrome.

**Updated:**
Your content type should be `application/json`.

Comment: thanks for reply but i had done changes based on your reference URL and i also check in Postman and Restclient when i send request using tool in form-data then i getting response success but when i send request using form-data from iOS programming then it give me the error.I am gettign success code 200 OK but i am not getting response we is getting in POSTMAN and RESTclient any idea ?