# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Tags: ios, json, bonjour

> Error Type : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.".UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

Scenario: Bonjour Server is able to send the JSON data successfully to the client. But sporadically I am seeing these errors: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840`.

Can anyone suggest how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set the

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
```

or Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233611/error-domain-nscocoaerrordomain-code-3840-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-u)

Comment: Hey @JigneshP I am getting data from Bonjour Server( here Apple Tv) not from Http. Can you please suggest me accordingly?