# AFNetorking in Swift project -- "Error: Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

Tags: ios, api, swift, afnetworking

I am implementing AFNetworking with CocoaPods into a Swift project. I am used to programming in Ruby and I am very new to iOS development. Cocoapods was tricky to get working properly in my project but I can now successfully access the AFNetworking library.

What I am trying to do is hit a form with a POST and get a response as "text/html" that I can parse so that I can tell if it saves. This is not an API per se, but a form generated by InfusionSoft. A user will enter an email address and I will send that off to an API for storage. Here is the code I am using:

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
            var parameters = ["inf_form_xid": "MY_ACCESS_ID",
                      "inf_form_name": "Webform in Content App",
                      "infusionsoft_version": "1.34.0.35",
                      "inf_field_email": self.emailTextField.text]

    manager.POST( "https://ns166.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/REALLYLONGUNIQUEID",
    parameters: parameters,
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

And the error that I am receiving this as a response from AFNetworking:

```
Error: Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html
```

At the end of the day, I want to verify that it was saved by the server before I allow the user to continue in the application.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html using AFNetworking 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0)

Comment: @mattt thanks but I'm looking for something that is Swift instead of OBJ-C

Comment: It's still the same question. The language used isn't all that important. It's really a question of AFNetworking's API.

Comment: @mattt but I still run into the problem where I am expecting text/html from the POST request but AFNetworking is saying that it's unacceptable. I need to add text/html as acceptable

Answer (score 5):

You have to add content-type allowed for the response.

You could do that for json content :

```
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects: "application/json")
```

**EDIT**

If you're using AFNetworking 2.0, from [AFNetworking wiki](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide) :

"By default, AFHTTPRequestOperationManager and AFHTTPSessionManager have JSON serializers."

So you should maybe try to change the response serializer in your manager like this :

```
manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
```

Comment: I am expecting text/html as a response. If I use your suggestion, but swap "application/json" for "text/html" it still won't work. I actually get a different error     Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: This error means that your response content is not good formatted. For example in JSON, if the JSON is not valid you will get this error. So can you edit your question with the response content that you expect?

Comment: when I made your suggestion with manager.responseSerializer I received the following response:     <0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d

Comment: Check your headers response, is there `charset` header? If not try adding it : `charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Or try doing this in your success response : `println((NSString(data: responseObject, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)))`

Answer (score 0):

This means that your server is sending "text/html" instead of the already supported types.You can either add acceptable content type as "text/html" or ensure that you are properly sending json format from the server side.By default the content type for afnetworking is json in objective c.Dont know about swift.
Reference :[Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html using AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0)

Comment: I am expecting the text/html. Unfortunately AFNetworking is expecting JSON and is getting hung up on the response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about swift but in objective c ,after searching for answer i came across the solution which working very well for me .
Below is the code snippet:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

AFJSONResponseSerializer *jsonResponseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableSet *jsonAcceptableContentTypes = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
[jsonAcceptableContentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
jsonResponseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = jsonAcceptableContentTypes;
operation.responseSerializer = jsonResponseSerializer;
```