# "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, asynchronous, afnetworking-2

I am trying below code but it gives error:

```
{    
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php"];    
 NSURLRequest *urlRequest =[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];    
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];    
 requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];    
 [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
        _imV.image = responseObject;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
    }];
    [requestOperation start];
}
```

Please help on me on `"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"` error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0

Answer (score 7):

Please try the following code:

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

this is to ensure you serialize the request & respond to HTTP instead of JSON.

Answer (score 3):

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

This worked for me. Looks like this is different from **AFNetworking 2.0**. Apparently in **3.0**, you need to explicitly provide a `requestSerializer` and a `responseSerializer`.