# Upload an sqlite file

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking to try to upload a file:

```
-(void)uploadFile{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
    NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://localhost:8888/myApp/upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePathURL name:@"file" fileName:@"data.sqlite" mimeType:@"text/html" error:nil];
    } error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSProgress *progress = nil;

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
        }
    }];

    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

And this php file `upload.php`:

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    echo "file=".$file;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo $file;
    }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
    ?>
```

It's printing:

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016
>   "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"
>   UserInfo=0x7b8b2bf0

Is the problem from the `mimeType` ? I also used `application/x-sqlite3` content type in both iOS and php sides.

Comment: You need a valid enctype when uploading files.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What could be "valid" in my case ?

Comment: I did notice you're using `AFMultipartFormData` however the `text/html` is the part that perplexes me. Usually a multi-part is what's used, but in your case, I'd try replacing `text/html` with `text/plain` try that and see what it says.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I already tested with `text/plain` but same problem.

Comment: @Rob You have reason, my bad, I replaced `file` with `uploadedFile` and changed the content type to `application/x-sqlite3`, the file UPLOADS but I don't know why it's showing the error `"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/x-sqlite3"`

Comment: Try `application/octet-stream` which is the fallback mime type for unknown binary streams. As RFC 2388 says, "As with all multipart MIME types, each part has an optional
   'Content-Type', which defaults to text/plain.  If the contents of a
   file are returned via filling out a form, then the file input is
   identified as the appropriate media type, if known, or
   'application/octet-stream'."

Comment: See if these Q&A's will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/19114623/

Comment: I'd also suggest supplying an `error` parameter to `multipartFormRequestWithMethod`. By the way, see my updated answer re `responseSerializer`.

Comment: You say "I also used `application/x-sqlite3` content type in both iOS and php sides." What do you mean by "php side"? The `header()` call?!? The `application/x-sqlite3` would be inappropriate there. There are two completely different `Content-Type` settings. One is the mime-type for the part of the multipart request in your client code (which should be `application/octet-stream` or `application/x-sqlite3`). The other is the header of the response in your PHP code (which should be `text/plain` for the current PHP code, or if you change PHP code to return JSON, it would be `application/json`).

Comment: @Rob: A very explained comments, perfect ! So the client part (iOS) is sending an sqlite file, so the mimeType would be `application/octet-stream` or `application/x-sqlite3`, and for the server side is returning in my case a plain text so the `content-type` would be `text/plain`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client-side code is uploading using the `file` field name, but the server code is looking for `uploadedfile`. You have to use the same field name on both platforms.

The mime type should be fixed. Because SQLite files are binary files, not text files, I'd suggest a mime type of `application/x-sqlite3` or `application/octet-stream`, rather than `text/html` or `text/plain`. But the mismatched field name is the more egregious issue.

---

By the way, you report an error message:

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x7b8b2bf0

This is generally a result that your server page is returning `text/html`, but `AFURLSessionManager` is expecting JSON.

You can change the manager's `responseSerializer`:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Or, better, change your server code to return JSON.

Comment: *"Because SQLite files are binary files, not text files"* - Ah, I didn't know that till now. I didn't mean to give bad info to the OP earlier about changing it to `text/plain`, my mistake. I'll remember that one.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob, you're always here for helping us. I have now a `success` response, and that's completely logic. Thank you and accepted !