# JSON Parsing getting Error NSErrorFailingURLKey in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, afnetworking-3

I am trying to print JSON response in first log.But whenever i try to get response from this [URL](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries/) and also from this [URL](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries/) .But whenever i make a request i am getting this error.

**NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries/, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data**

This is my Log File

```
  2016-01-15 12:19:25.618 JSOnParsingWithActorList[3153:58905] Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x78e25230> { URL: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries/ } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=3600";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 490;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Fri, 15 Jan 2016 06:27:55 GMT";
    Expires = "Fri, 15 Jan 2016 07:27:55 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries/, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b22636f 756e7472 69657322 3a5b7b22 636f756e 7472796e 616d6522 3a22496e 64696122 2c22666c 6167223a 22687474 703a5c2f 5c2f7770 74726166 66696361 6e616c79 7a65722e 696e5c2f 705c2f64 656d6f31 5c2f696e 6469612e 706e6722 2c226c61 6e677561 6765223a 2248696e 6469222c 22636170 6974616c 223a224e 65772044 656c6869 222c2263 75727265 6e637922 3a7b2263 6f646522 3a22494e 52222c22 63757272 656e6379 6e616d65 223a2252 75706565 227d7d2c 7b22636f 756e7472 796e616d 65223a22 50616b69 7374616e 222c2266 6c616722 3a226874 74703a5c 2f5c2f77 70747261 66666963 616e616c 797a6572 2e696e5c 2f705c2f 64656d6f 315c2f70 616b6973 74616e2e 706e6722 2c226c61 6e677561 6765223a 22557264 75222c22 63617069 74616c22 3a224973 6c616d61 62616422 2c226375 7272656e 6379223a 7b22636f 6465223a 22504b52 222c2263 75727265 6e63796e 616d6522 3a225061 6b697374 616e6920 52757065 65227d7d 2c7b2263 6f756e74 72796e61 6d65223a 22537269 204c616e 6b61222c 22666c61 67223a22 68747470 3a5c2f5c 2f777074 72616666 6963616e 616c797a 65722e69 6e5c2f70 5c2f6465 6d6f315c 2f737269 6c616e6b 612e706e 67222c22 6c616e67 75616765 223a2253 696e6861 6c61222c 22636170 6974616c 223a2253 7269204a 61796177 61726465 6e617075 7261204b 6f747465 222c2263 75727265 6e637922 3a7b2263 6f646522 3a22534b 52222c22 63757272 656e6379 6e616d65 223a2253 7269204c 616e6b61 6e205275 70656522 7d7d2c7b 22636f75 6e747279 6e616d65 223a2243 68696e61 222c2266 6c616722 3a226874 74703a5c 2f5c2f77 70747261 66666963 616e616c
```

I am using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for making URL call.I check this url's in Android.This URL content-type is Application/JSON but in IOS i am getting header content-type text/html.From this [URL](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/) I am getting sucessful response from URL in JSON format.Please help for solve this issue.

This is my ViewController.m file

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@",response);
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code:

```
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

After this :

```
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
```

It is well explained here : [Upload an sqlite file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638318/upload-an-sqlite-file)

> Your server page is returning text/html, but AFURLSessionManager is expecting JSON.

**Edit:**

As the above solution didn't work out , i found this link containing all possible solution for this error : [Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0)

Comment: I just write only mention above code in my project nothing else.

Comment: also this : `manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];`

Comment: and this: `manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;`

Comment: Check my edited answer for link. There you will find multiple possible solution for this issue.