# How to sign up through Rest API using AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

**I have to make parameter like this**

```
array( 
‘token’,
‘data’ => array( ‘name’,
                 ‘email’,
                 ‘password’,
  ) 
)
```

As I am a beginner to use REST API service. So I can't able to make this. **I tried the following way to request**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"name" : name,
                             @"email" : email,
                             @"password" : password};
    [manager POST:BASE_URL  parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

**Got a respose like this**

```
Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0x7f965071adc0 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9650721f80> { URL: BASE_URL } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 15 Sep 2015 16:33:10 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.0";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, NSErrorFailingURLKey=BASE_URL
```

Is there any mistake to POST the request for sign up? What is the correct way to request? Please help.

Comment: What content type are you expecting to get back? Is it possible your server is not sending the data back in an unexpected format? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19121229/620197

Comment: am I sending the parameters in a correct way @MikeD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//edited
   NSDictionary *innerDict = @{@"name":name,@"email":email,@"password":password};
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data":innerDict};
NSArray *parameter = @[@token,@dict];
[manager POST:BASE_URL  parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];//add this line
```

Include the last line i added.There might be some syntax error coz i am in a windows machine now, but xcode will auto complete for you, if you write it down on your own.

That should do it now.

Comment: After doing this, I am getting the following 


Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7fc37bdf9d10 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: write this code inside the failure block `NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);` and see what is it printing?

Comment: getting some html and CSS code

onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr55f84f20d734e-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr55f84f20d734e-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');"><b>Warning</b> (2)</a>: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [<b>APP/Plugin/Api/Controller/ApiAppController.php</b>, line <b>39</b>]<div id="cakeErr55f84f20d734e-trace" class="cake-stack-trace" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr55f84f20d734e-code').style.display =

Comment: That means the server is NOT returning a JSON, and the data the server is returning must start with an array and by the recent comment you posted it means in your ApiAppController.php file Line number 39 there seems to be some mistake. Please rectify it.

Comment: @SahebRoy check the parameters, which are expecting from the server side, they are not accessing the parameters as key-value pair, they are accessing them as array.

Comment: AFNetworking converts them into JSON before sending them which is wrapped into an string array format before it hits the server.

Comment: there is difference between jsonobject and jsonarray.

Comment: Yes i just noticed the structure he needed and normally in any REST service a structure such as this isnt recommended, anyways am editing the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for parameters:

```
NSString *token = // Fill token
NSString *name = // Fill Name
NSString *email = // Fill Email
NSString *password = // Fill Password
NSDictionary *params = @[token,@{@"data": @[name,email,password]}];
```

Comment: NSString *token = // Fill token

Comment: Its showing an warning like this      Incompatible pointer initializing "NSDictionary *" with a expression of type "NSArray *"

Comment: NSArray *params = @[token,@{@"data": @[name,email,password]}];

Comment: But in AFNetworking the parameter is a Dictionary type. So please need a dictionary to pass a data I mentioned

Comment: but you data mentioned start with Array, you need more help plz give me url and other infomation