# How to get the content of URL using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking

[Here](http://www.taboo.blue-world.pl/api/identifiers/pl-normal.json) is the content I need to download to my app.

This is how I request this:

```
GET("identifiers/pl-normal.json", parameters: nil, progress: nil, success: { sessionDataTask, response in


    }) { sessionDataTask, error in
        completionBlock(error)
}
```

URL Request is correct: `GET Optional(http://www.taboo.blue-world.pl/api/identifiers/pl-normal.json)`

but the `failure` block is called, why?

Comment: You could start by telling us what error you are getting.

Comment: `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.` - this is a content of error.

Answer (score 0):

The error block will be called in `AFNetworking` if results of the network request cannot be parsed properly. In other words, this is a serialization error.  It looks like the content you are getting is not properly formatted json. Run your server response through a json linter and make sure it is valid, and you should be all set.

If that doesn't work, try adding text/html as an acceptable content type in your serializer, as described here - [Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html using AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0)