# Network error when installed application from IPA via iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, itunes, ipa

I have created an application and generated IPA file for development deployment. I am using `AFNetworking` to make network calls.

The problem is that when I attach the `iPhone 5s` and run in debug mode everything works fine but when I generate IPA and install it via `iTunes` it generates `AFNetworking` error code `200` unacceptable content-type text/html.

I don't understand how that could happen. I created development provisioning profile and made sure that it is used while creating archive.

Comment: Can you post code where you call webservice ?

Comment: The error is related to the content type you receive and how you have handled it and not due to the profiles or ipa creation

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0

Comment: I forgot to mention that it happens with all the web services in the application called using AFNetworking.

Comment: @vishnuvarthan, I know how to handle this error if it does not work at all. But it does work in simulator and on real device if installed using xcode. It does not work only if installed using IPA.

Comment: Did you try calling the service in browser/print the response data and check if you get the correct response, may be your service got updated or changed when you installed it using IPA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have tried so many times in device and simulator with xcode and itunes but nothing changes. I'm going to try to reinstall pod for `AFNetworking` and check it on tomorrow. Hope it helps. I will reply you with the result.