# AFNETWORKING 3.0 Post Request Fail

Tags: objective-c

I sent a request to server using `AFNETWORKING 3.0` with the following parameters:

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; 
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];           
[parameters setObject:_texLoginUname.text forKey:@"ent_email"]; 
[parameters setObject:_textLoginPassword.text forKey:@"ent_password"];     
[parameters setObject:uniqueIdentifier forKey:@"ent_device_id"]; 
[parameters setObject:@"2" forKey:@"eat_device_type"]; 
[parameters setObject:@"22" forKey:@"ent_device_token"];
```

Here is my code:

```
NSString *URL = @"http://optime.in/apps/food_truck/user_api/login";

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[manager POST:URL parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"success!");

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    NSData *errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
    NSDictionary *serializedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: errorData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"val = %@",serializedData);

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error while sending POST"
                                                        message:@"Sorry, try again."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}];
```

**And i got this error:**

> NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404), 
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7be19ef0 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"
>
> UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=http://optime.in/apps/food_truck/user_api/login } { status code: 404, headers {
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 302;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
>       Date = "Tue, 20 Sep 2016 08:12:20 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
>       Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
>   } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=@"mylink"
>   , NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html,

Kindly help me to solve this error.

Comment: and this is my code I m using........

Comment: this is my parameters i want to send

Comment: this code i m using

Comment: edit your ques don't comment here any long code like you comment ..

Comment: Please put that code in your question (edit it), and also try to format it. `unacceptable content-type: text/html,` seems to be a good hint on what is wrong.

Comment: This question is related to AFNetworking 2.0, but it should explains the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114623/request-failed-unacceptable-content-type-text-html-using-afnetworking-2-0 and a small workaround should be able to be done in AFNetworking 3.0

Answer (score 2):

you should use below Method because `AFJSONRequestSerializer` is not working is AFNetworking 3.0

This method can work because I use this and only method

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; 
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];           
[parameters setObject:_texLoginUname.text forKey:@"ent_email"]; 
[parameters setObject:_textLoginPassword.text forKey:@"ent_password"];     
[parameters setObject:uniqueIdentifier forKey:@"ent_device_id"]; 
[parameters setObject:@"2" forKey:@"eat_device_type"]; 
[parameters setObject:@"22" forKey:@"ent_device_token"]; 
NSString *URL = @"http://optime.in/apps/food_truck/user_api/login";

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
    [manager POST:URL parameters:_parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"success!");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Hope this thing works